# How to open devtools automatically when application is starting?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

How to can I configure `Node Webkit` for open devtools automatically when my application is started?

Can I do it from `package.json` configure or `javascript`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can enable the devtools by adding **"showDevToolsOnStartup":true** under developer section in package.json and can open devtools automatically when application is started.

```
{
    "main": "index.html",
    "name": "nw-demo",
    "description": "demo app of node-webkit",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "keywords": [ "demo", "node-webkit" ],
    "window": {
        "title": "node-webkit demo",
        "icon": "link.png",
        "toolbar": true,
        "frame": false,
        "width": 800,
        "height": 500,
        "position": "mouse",
        "min_width": 400,
        "min_height": 200,
        "max_width": 800,
        "max_height": 600
    },
    "developer": {
        "showDevToolsOnStartup": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could run some JavaScript on page load which calls `showDevTools` on the window.

This works with nw.js v0.11.6.

```
<head>
  <script>
    function openDevTools()
    {
        require('nw.gui').Window.get().showDevTools();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="openDevTools()">
```

Further details in the nw.js documentation here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/window#windowshowdevtoolsid--iframe-headless

Comment: Thank you so so much! This is what I need

Answer (score 4):

for nw.js 0.13 and newer you can use:

```
nw.Window.get().showDevTools();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around for a solution regarding this myself and couldn't really find a satisfactory answer. You might have to try using f12 in javascript or a keystroke solution.

Comment: Be cause I'm create application in `Node Webkit`, maybe hotkey is working to this

Comment: but after npm install nw i run the app without any F12 working ... is there anything i missed?

Answer (score -2):

It's not likely to ever happen or be allowed to happen, quite intentionally, as it's considered a security flaw.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277

Comment: not allowing developers to debug their code is considered a security flaw.